# .NET Regex Instance Caching

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150514231020/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/10/19/regex-class-caching-changes-between-net-framework-1-1-and-net-framework-2-0-josh-free.aspx), which describes how instance vs static methods get called with a .NET regex.

However, what about if the variable itself is static? Does anyone know if .NET does any sort of caching that could potentially cause a memory leak?

Clarification. For example:

```
public static Regex Foo = new Regex(@"(?:,.*)");
```

versus:

```
public static void MyMethod(){
  Regex Foo = new Regex(@"(?:,.*)");
}
```

Is either of those more likely to cause any memory issues than the other? I know the second one will obviously create more instances, but does the first one have any sort of caching of incoming strings to worry about, since it will essentially sit around forever.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an instantiated Regex object and you are only calling instance methods on it, then cacheing (according to the supplied article) will not occur. If you create the Regex object and store it as a static property in your class, you are still dealing with an instantiated object, hence the cacheing will not occur (>=.net 2.0).

On the other hand, every time you call Regex static methods, such as Regex.Match("bla","bla"), the parsed and compiled regular expressions will be cached.

EDIT

Looking at your example, cacheing will not occur in either case. If however, the second example was:

```
Match m=Regex.Match(@"(?:,.*)",someString);
```

... then the compiled regular expression `(?:,.*)` will be cached, so you can efficiently make subsequent calls to `Regex.Match(@"(?:,.*)",...` without needing to reparse/recompile the expression `(?:,.*)`. I guess in terms of memory consumption, this would equate almost exactly to keeping a static instance. On the other hand, if the regular expression supplied to Regex.Match changed, then an additional entry would be made at some (probably negligible) expense.

Comment: I'm not confused, I know exactly what was happening; I'm just curious if there's any caching *at all* that goes on in instances of a Regex.

Comment: removed, for fear of causing offence :)

Comment: None taken :) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a "static instance" - there are just static *variables* which refer to objects. The same object can be referred to by an instance variable, a local variable or a static variable. It won't change any of the code within the `Regex` constructor.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Poor wording. The question's been updated. But the question is still valid - if a given instance of a Regex does any sort of caching (ie, caching of the incoming string passed to myRegex.Match or some such nonsense), then it would make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class, there is some caching that the framework will do for you at runtime.  It does compile them before caching them. However, the can only take advantage of the caching if you are using the `static` Regex methods as explained below. This has been around since .NET Framework 1.0 and is still present as of today (currently .NET 8). It only makes sense to utilize the built-in caching in a couple of scenarios:

### When should I use the "built-in" `Regex` caching?

1. You have *less than* 16 distinct regular expressions that are used **within the entire Application Domain**. This is because there is a limit of regular expressions that are cached - and this value is a static member of the `Regex` class (i.e. shared by all instances of `Regex` across the . The size of this limit is controlled by the [Regex.CacheSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.cachesize?view=net-7.0#remarks) property. It has a default value of **15** (which has been the same for all versions of .NET to date). This value *can* be changed if necessary. I don't usually recommend this though - see Recommendations #1.
2. The regular expression is "constant" - not necessarily that the string representing it is constant (though that is a good idea), but that it doesn't change from invocation to invocation.

### How do I use the "built-in" `Regex` caching?

The only way to take advantage of the caching is to use the `static` methods `Regex.IsMatch(...)` or `Regex.Match(...)`. So in your example, you would do something like this:

```
public static void MyMethod(string testInput)
{
    bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(testInput, @"(?:,.*)");
    ...
}
```

### Recommendations

1. I don't like the idea of leaving caching to the framework mainly for the reason that you may end up with additional static usage of Regex at some point in the future, have static Regex usage in another class, or the biggest concern of having static Regex usage in another dll or even third-party dependency that you have no idea about! So I usually create a `static readonly Regex` instance as a member of the class where it's used and re-use it as needed:

```
private static readonly Regex _myRegex = new Regex(@"(?:,.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled /* add any other RegexOptions you need here as well */);
```

2. It is a good idea to use `RegexOptions.Compiled` so it is compiled to MSIL code, instead of being interpreted at runtime. Compiled regular expressions maximize run-time performance at the expense of the smallest amount of initialization time - see [RegexOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-7.0)